# How to put the name of another java file (or class) next to the name of a method?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, count, compiler-errors

My professor made a list of methods that I should write or make changes to. One of them she has listed as Customer getCustomer(String n). Now customer is the name of another java file that will be used later to make the code work correctly but I almost sure that getCustomer is the name I'm supposed to make the method. Below I will copy and paste the code that I wrote for this method and then I will post the compile error. Please help me get this code to compile.

```
public void Customer getCustomer(String username){
   for(int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
   String holdingSpotForArrayEle;
   holdingSpotForArrayEle = customerList.get(i); 
   if (holdingSpotForArrayEle == username)
   return username;
   }
   }
```

Do you see the first line of code here thats where the error is regarding.

The compile error is as follows:

```
CustomerDatabase.java:77: error: '(' expected
   public void Customer getCustomer(String username){
                        ^
1 error
```

(By the way the small carrot sign is below the g in getCustomer.)
If you're thinking get rid of customer, the professor included customer in the beginning of the method by referring to the method as Customer getCustomer(String n).

Comment: `public void Customer getCustomer(String username){` you have defined 2 return types

Comment: The prof. gave you the exact method signature to use: `Customer getCustomer(String n) {...}`.

Comment: Also, don't use `==` to compare strings.  Instead of `holdingSpotForArrayEle == username`, use `holdingSpotForArrayEle.equals(username)`.

Comment: The method `getCustomer` is supposed to return a `Customer` so the `void` before it makes no sense. Because now java thinks that you are declaring a method named `Customer` with no return type `void` and that there should be a `(` after it but it encounters the `getCustomer` token. So it says *error at g*. What you really want is to not have `void`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Customer getCustomer(String username)
```

is an incorrect signature of a method.

Also looking at the return statement within your code

```
return username; // check type of username
```

the current signature would be to return `String` which is also the type of `username` :

```
public String getCustomer(String username)
```

---

In order to return the type `Customer`, you method definition should be updated to use:

```
return new Customer(); // just for example
```

and then the matching method signature would be

```
public Customer getCustomer(String username)
```